# Aligning two rows of flex items into columns

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a flex div as you can see below, but the buttons don't align with the boxes below.

How can I make them align with each other (the top to the bottom) while still having the flex?

Any ideas help. Thanks!

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
}
.flex-child {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  margin-right: 5px;
}
.boxed-flex {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  margin-right: 5px;
  border: 4px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <button class="flex-child" onclick="circumfrance()">Circumfrance</button>
  <button class="flex-child" onclick="area()">Area</button>
  <button class="flex-child" onclick="diameter()">Radius &rarr; Diameter</button>
  <button class="flex-child" onclick="radius()">Diameter &rarr; Radius</button>
</div>

<div class="flex">
  <div class="boxed-flex">
    <strong><p id="circumfrance"style="color:purple;"></p></strong>
  </div>
  <div class="boxed-flex">
    <strong><p id="area"style="color:purple;"></p></strong>
  </div>
  <div class="boxed-flex">
    <strong><p id="diameter"style="color:purple;" ></p></strong>
  </div>
  <div class="boxed-flex">
    <strong><p id="radius" style="color:purple;"></p></strong>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You are sizing the flex items with `flex: 1 1 auto`. This is shorthand for:

- `flex-grow: 1`
- `flex-shrink: 1`
- `flex-basis: auto`

The problem is the last component.

With `flex-basis: auto` you're sizing the items based on their width. But the widths of the button and the green boxes are different. Hence, the columns don't align.

Instead, use `flex: 1 1 0` (which is the same as `flex: 1`).

This sets the `flex-basis` to 0. Now the items will simply distribute free space in the container evenly among themselves.

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
}
.flex-child {
  flex: 1;
  margin-right: 5px;
}
.boxed-flex {
  flex: 1;
  margin-right: 5px;
  border: 4px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <button class="flex-child" onclick="circumfrance()">Circumfrance</button>
  <button class="flex-child" onclick="area()">Area</button>
  <button class="flex-child" onclick="diameter()">Radius &rarr; Diameter</button>
  <button class="flex-child" onclick="radius()">Diameter &rarr; Radius</button>
</div>

<div class="flex">
  <div class="boxed-flex">
    <strong><p id="circumfrance"style="color:purple;"></p></strong>
  </div>
  <div class="boxed-flex">
    <strong><p id="area"style="color:purple;"></p></strong>
  </div>
  <div class="boxed-flex">
    <strong><p id="diameter"style="color:purple;" ></p></strong>
  </div>
  <div class="boxed-flex">
    <strong><p id="radius" style="color:purple;"></p></strong>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add width:0 to your button class, and it will work. Because, buttons have default auto-sized widths. This way it will prevent auto sizing.

```
.flex-child {
    -webkit-box-flex: 1 1 auto;
    -moz-box-flex:  1 1 auto;
    -webkit-flex:  1 1 auto;
    -ms-flex:  1 1 auto;
    flex:  1 1 auto;
    margin-right:5px;
    width: 0px;
}
```